Why are my 3d model appearing artifact-y

Why do my 3d models look like a lego brick? The artifacts appear here only in Eevee, and only in the viewport. It doesn't appear in any render or viewport render, just on the screen. It happens to all 3d models, no matter what, in any file. that's all I know.

That looks like a graphics driver problem to me. Make sure that your graphics card is supported in the version of Blender that you are using and that you have the latest graphics driver from the maufacturer installed.
